# Windows batch file to move files from specific subfolders to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I am a php developer and I know nothing about windows batch files.
Maybe somebody will help me...

I have a directory structure like here:

> ```
> directory1/1/
> directory1/2/
> directory1/5/
> directory2/1/
> directory2/2/
> directory2/5/
> etc...
> ```

How can I write a bat file that will do the following:
-move all files from all sub-directories '1' into a different directory

I had tried this

```
pushd %CD%\in\
for /r %%a in (*.*) do (
 echo COPY "%%a" "%CD%\out\%%~nxa"
)
popd
```

but this code takes all the files from "in" folder and copies them to "out" folder. How can I determine subdirectories here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this batch command:

```
@echo off
::Set Directory
set Dir=%CD%\in
::Set Destination
set Des=%CD%\out
::Set Sub Directory you want to move
set SubDir=1
if exist "%Dir%\*" (
    if not exist "%Des%\*" mkdir "%Des%"
    for /D %%a in ("%Dir%\*.*") do (
        for /D %%b in ("%%a\*.*") do (
            if "%%~nxb" EQU "%SubDir%" ROBOCOPY "%%b" "%Des%\%%~nxa\%%~nxb" /E /IS /MOVE>Nul
        )
    )
)
```